# biblatex: How to only have first name initials when a reference would be identical? (Instead of for all authors with same last name)

Tags: biblatex

so this is the biblatex code I currently use.

However, I want to **only** have authors' first name initials, whenever these are really needed. With needed I mean two or more references would be identical, if there were not the first author's first name initial.

```
\usepackage[
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=false,
  hyperref=true,
  style=authoryear,
  useprefix=true, % for inclusion of 'de' 'da' in surname,
   labeldate=year, 
   alldates=year, 
   urldate=short,
  nohashothers=true,
  natbib=true
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Currently I get also initials for A. Smith (1776) and P. Smith (2019) which is not allowed in the citation style I have to use.

In my references.bib I have 3 people called Li. But only 2 need initials as Li et al. (2017) is identical without the initial (or naming one Li et al. (2017b) and the other (2017b), which I do not want). But Li et al. 2015 does not need a first name initial.

```
@article{LiX2017,
    title = {{Impacts of renewables and socioeconomic factors on electric vehicle demands – Panel data studies across 14 countries}},
    year = {2017},
    journal = {Energy Policy},
    author = {Li, Xiaomin and Chen, Pu and Wang, Xingwu},
    month = {10},
    pages = {473--478},
    volume = {109},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    issn = {0301-4215}
}

@article{LiS2017,
    title = {{The Market for Electric Vehicles: Indirect Network Effects and Policy Design}},
    year = {2017},
    journal = {Journal of the Association of Environmental and Resource Economists},
    author = {Li, Shanjun and Tong, Lang and Xing, Jianwei and Zhou, Yiyi},
    number = {1},
    month = {3},
    pages = {89--133},
    volume = {4},
    doi = {10.1086/689702},
    issn = {2333-5955},
    keywords = {A04, Electric Vehicles, Electric vehicles, Indirect Network Effects, Indirect network effects, Policy Design, Policy design, Q03, R05}
}

@article{LI2015,
    title = {{Policies and Business Models for the Electric Mobility Revolution}},
    year = {2015},
    journal = {The Singapore Economic Review},
    author = {LI, YANFEI and KOCHHAN, ROBERT},
    number = {0},
    pages = {1550109},
    volume = {0},
    url = {http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S021759081550109X},
    doi = {10.1142/S021759081550109X},
    issn = {0217-5908},
    keywords = {arf, battery cost, battery electric vehicles, bev, jel classification, n70, policy, q42, r48, singapore, supportive, tco, total cost of ownership}
}
```

This is basically the same as this 5-year-old question but I don't see why I cannot seem to fix this. [biblatex: Name disambiguation only for FIRST author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303546/biblatex-name-disambiguation-only-for-first-author) I use overleaf so I guess I have the newest versions.

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. Also, note that Overleaf is not running the very latest versions of packages; currently we run TeX Live 2020 with biblatex v.3.16. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: Hey thanks, can you tell me how to find Version in overleaf? Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can find them in the logs sometimes. If that's not the case, you can add `\listfiles` as the first command in your main document. Then, near the end of the log file, there will be a list of all loaded files including short descriptions and version information. (That's really how I got the version number, simply `\listfiles \documentclass{article} \usepackage{biblatex} \begin{document} Hello, world! \end{document}` and then check the logs.)